# Have Install4j installer display --version info

Tags: java, install4j

I create a set of installers with install4j, and would like a quick way to check the version info of the installer executable

Traditionally, this would involve calling something like `installer-name.sh --version`

Ideally, this would work without needing to unpack the bundled JRE, but I notice that even the `-h` help for install4j installers unpacks the JRE, so I am assuming that is not an option...

What I'd like to know is:

- Is there any way to specify options like `-h`, which do one task (like print version info), and then exit gracefully
- Alternatively, if I will need to parse out this option myself using `context.getExtraCommandLineArguments()`, is there a way to successfully exit an installation after a certain action runs, without needing to force a "Quit on failure".

  - I'd like to avoid a situation where I have one action which handles a `--version` and then the rest of my installation in a conditional group.

==============

To be clear what I mean by the last point is that I would like a solution like (framing install4j installation actions as a Java function):

```
if(versionRequested){
  printVersion();
  return;
}
//all the rest of my installation actions
```

rather than:

```
if(versionRequested){
  printVersion();
}
else{
  //all the rest of my installation actions
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Startup" node of the installer, add a "Run script" action with the script

```
if (Arrays.asList(context.getExtraCommandLineArguments()).contains("--version")) {
    System.out.println("Version " + context.getCompilerVariable("sys.version"));
    context.finish(0);
}
return true;
```

On Windows, `System.out.println` will not print to the console, because the installer is a GUI application, so you would have to call

```
Util.showMessage("Version " + context.getCompilerVariable("sys.version"));
```

which also behaves correctly in console mode.